# exporting in SAS multiple datasets

Tags: sas

I have a set of datasets which I would like to output in an Excel File. Is there a way to do this quickly rather than calling proc export each time for each dataset

%let MyDS = ('out.Ids', 'out.Vars', 'out.Places')

%let MyDSname = (Ids, Vars, Places)

I would like to create a macro that check if each dataset exists and then output to an Excel spreadsheet with the Tab name as specified in the corresponding MyDSname ...

Something like... %macro Out(MySpreadsheetName, MyDS, MyDSname);

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `Access to PC Files` licensed, the easiest way to do this (export several datasets to one workbook) is with a libname.

```
libname mywbk excel 'c:\pathtomyexcel\excelfile.xlsx';

data mywbk.nameoftab;
set dataset;
run;
```

In terms of conditionally creating this, you should look at how you're arriving at the list of names to export.  In general, you should have a dataset that contains one row per dataset to export, and two columns - DS name and tab name.  You can then merge that to `sashelp.vtables` or `dictionary.tables` which are views containing the list of tables in the current SAS session; `memname` is the name of the table, `libname` is the name of the library.  Then create a macro call from that:

```
proc sql;
select cats('%out(',dsname,',',tabname,')') into :calllist separated by ' '
from joinedds;
quit;

libname ... ;
&calllist.;
```

Comment: ok im still confused about the memname not sure how to access that?

Comment: `memname` is the variable containing the name of the dataset.  You can look at it via something like `data test; set sashelp.vtable; run;`, and then join/merge to a dataset that contains the table names, on `memname`.